# Spring how to create bean with constructor that contains a variable

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have the following object which I want to replace with a bean:

```
file = new File( filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
```

I tried:

```
<bean id="fileone" class="java.io.File">
<constructor-arg type="String" value="filePath + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf(&quot;\\&quot;)+1)"/>
</bean>
```

With the eventual goal of having this line of code:

```
file=fileone
```

However I get error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: filePath + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\")+1)
```

What is the reason for this error? In what way do I modify the bean?

Comment: Where are you keeping values for filePath & fileName?

Comment: inside the java code

Comment: Then why don't you use those directly in the File object?

Comment: because they are variables and hence dynamic and will change all the time

Comment: seems impossible, bean is held in context, will is a singleton object. if the value keeping changed, you should use new.